# DragonFly BSD purpose myth: one OS on several physical machines?

Tags: dragonflybsd

Long ago I read/heard something about DragonFlyBSD that one of its purpose is to run one OS on multiple physical machines. Or something like "the outside" can see only one OS, but underneath it runs on several physical machines.

I cannot find this "myth/purpose", but I am remembering it that I read it somewhere.

The **Question**: can anybody confirm or refute it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This information is easily Google-able.

Yes, DragonFly BSD is intending to support ["single system image clustering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_system_image) at some point, as mentioned on [the project's history web page](https://www.dragonflybsd.org/history/).

> DragonFly BSD has been going through rapid and ever increasing development since the fork. One of the important works included the simplification and general cleanup of the majority of the kernel subsystems. **This work was originally intended to support single system image clustering**, but has had the effect of making the kernel much more reliable, understandable and easily maintainable. One of the fundamental synchronization concepts that DragonFly uses throughout the kernel, the token, lends itself directly to ease of maintenance and understandability of the kernel.
>
> **During the first major phase of the project, which lasted until early 2007, the DragonFly project focused on rewriting most of the major kernel subsystems to implement required abstractions and to support mechanics for the second phase of the project, which at the time was intended to be single system image clustering**. This involved a great deal of work in nearly every subsystem, particularly the filesystem APIs and kernel core. During this time a paramount goal was to keep the system updated with regard to the third party applications and base system utilities needed to make any system usable in production. This resulted in the adoption of the pkgsrc framework for management of all non-base-system third-party applications in order to pool our resources with other BSD projects using this framework.
>
> In the 2007-2008 time frame, a new filesystem called HAMMER was developed for DragonFly BSD. HAMMER saw its first light of day in July 2008 with the DragonFly 2.0 release. This filesystem has been designed to solve numerous issues and to add many new capabilities to DragonFly, such as fine-grained history retention (snapshots), instant crash recovery, and near real-time mirroring. **The HAMMER filesystem is also intended to serve as a basis for the clustering and other work that makes up the second phase of the project**.

Note that in the most recent release of the operating system ([release 5.0](https://www.dragonflybsd.org/release50/)), HAMMER2 does not support clustering.

Also read this (somewhat old) InformIT article: [DragonFly BSD: UNIX for Clusters?](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=766375).